# n! and 2^(n^2); which one grows faster

Tags: asymptotics

I can't figure this out; is $2^{n^2}=O(n!)$ or is it the other way around? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you go from n to n+1, what is n! multiplied with, and what is 2^(n^2) multiplied with?

Comment: for a quick intuition, try substituting some sufficiently large value and compare them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$n! = 1\times 2\times … \times n \leqslant n \times n\times… \times n = n^n \leqslant (2^n)^n = 2^{n^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with their logarithm, since O(log(n!)) = O(nlogn) and O(log(2^(n^2)) = O(n^2) and nlogn < n^2. So the later one grows faster.

Comment: Obviously be careful if the expressions for the logarithms are closer together.

Comment: Big-O of the original expressions are the same if the logarithms differ at most by a constant. In this case, the difference between n log n and n^2 is more than any constant, so 2^(2^n)) is asymptotically larger than n!